# Block-scoped declarations ... TypeScript and Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, typescript

I try use in my asp.net mvc5 project TypeScript. I create app.ts file and install nuget-package
**jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped**.
app.ts code:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>

class TestClass {
    test(): void {
        alert("Taras TS");
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var tcs: TestClass = new TestClass();
    $('#taras').click(() => { tcs.test() });
};
```

It's very simple code. And after it I create index.cshtml file, where created some button with **id='taras'**, code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "tmp";
}

<button id="taras"> TS EVENT </button>

@section scripts{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.ts")"></script>
}
```

I think it is healthy code, but I catch next exception in google chrome debug console:

> app.ts:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const,
>   function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Why it happens? And how to fix it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url.Content only transforms a relative path to an absolute one. It won't be changing the file extension.

The browser can't read your .ts file (hence that error, as it doesn't understand TypeScript syntax). Change the file extension to the compiled .js file:

```
@section scripts{
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app.js")"></script>
}
```